# Why does assigning int(0) to a string index end the loop?

Tags: c, for-loop, break

This is a puzzle I encountered.

I get no errors when I compile it:

`$gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99`

Can you please explain why this happens in C?

**Expected**:

Print out the index and char at the str[i] and replace

**Output:**

If I try to reassign str[i] to 0, it acts as a break for the for-loop.

```
    char str[] = "this is only a test";
    for(int i = 0; i < (int)strlen(str); i++) {
        printf("str[%d] = %c\n", i, str[i]);
        if(str[i] == ' ') {
               str[i] = 0; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hint: What does `strlen` do?

Comment: It's odd to see `char str[]` instead of the more traditional `char str*`.

Comment: at least `char str[]` is legal. The other flavour creates a string literal you cannot write to.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Ah, yes, that is true in this case where what should be a constant string is being modified.

Comment: @melpomene `strlen` counts the number of char up until the null string char. Does this mean that the str[i] = 0 line adds a null string char to str[]?

Comment: @Vince What do you think a "null string char" is?

Comment: @melpomene In ascii, the literal is '\0' . It is the string terminator and it signals whatever is ready the string that the string terminates/ends at that point.

Comment: @Vince No, in C the literal is `'\0'`. Or `0`. They're the same thing.

Comment: Oh that's interesting. That does explain it now! Thanks! @melpomene

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your program works fine** (assuming you have included `string.h`) - when it finds space `' '` as a character, it sets the **ith** index to `\0` and when next time `strlen` calculates the length, it finds that `i<(int)strlen` (it finds termination at early position) is violated and the loop terminates.

Here is the output on **GCC** without any warning/error:

```
 str[0] = t
 str[1] = h
 str[2] = i
 str[3] = s
 str[4] =
```

The only thing is, it will not print the entire string as when you find space character you replace it will null termination, next time `strlen` condition gets violated and it comes out of the loop.

For printing the entire string better use a variable and initialize it with length of string and then use that variable as condition:

```
 unsigned length = strlen(str);
 for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
```

Plus you don't need to typecast `strlen`'s return value to `int`.

Comment: If you don't cast, you'll get a warning about comparing signed/unsigned integers. The real solution is to give `i` the right type in the first place.

Comment: @melpomene Updated that but don't think in this case it would be needed + GCC didn't give any warning with `Wall` and `Wextra`?

Comment: `.code.tio.c:6:22: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘size_t’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]` Happens with `-Wextra`.

Comment: @melpomene What version you are using, mine is: 8.2.0 (nothing with -Wextra here).

Comment: I'm using gcc 8.1.1. What's the exact command line you're using?

Comment: @melpomene I tried all these three and got nothing: `1>  gcc -Wall -Wextra -o m m.c --pedantic` then `2> gcc -Wall -Wextra -o m m.c` and then removed `-Wall`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180552/discussion-between-melpomene-and-observer).

Comment: @melpomene: This is a great example of why it's wrong to blindly insert casts to shut up warnings. The right fix would be to use the correct type for `i`, `size_t`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're manipulating the string and calling `strlen` on it repeatedly you're getting into trouble here. Remember that the `for` termination condition is evaluated *each time through the loop*, not once.

To fix this:

```
size_t l = strlen(str); // Save the length once

for (size_t i = 0; i < l; i++) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: @user3121023 It only terminates early because it's evaluated each time.